# Angular jspdf [atob] problem with custom font (greek characters)

Tags: angular, jspdf

I try to generate an pdf from the **service** with greek characters.
on my local machine it's work's good. but on real server I'm getting error

> **sPDF PubSub Error Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. DOMException: Failed to
> execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly
> encoded.**

**.ttf** file is in service folder

I call this function from my component. **service code is:**

```
...//some imports

public printSomeData(data: any) {
    // getting data to the parse

      doc.addFileToVFS('Adria Slab W00 Medium.ttf')
      doc.addFont('Adria Slab W00 Medium.ttf', 'Adria Slab W00 Medium', 'normal')
      doc.setFont('Adria Slab W00 Medium', 'sans-serif')


      doc.setFontSize(data.fontSize)

      let body = []
      // generate body code

      autoTable(doc,{
        head: [head],
        body: body,
        tableLineColor: [189, 195, 199],
        tableLineWidth: 0.75,
        theme: 'grid',
        // headStyles: {co},
        bodyStyles: {lineColor: [0, 0, 0]},

        styles: {
          font: 'Adria Slab W00 Medium',    // <-- custom font
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontSize: data.fontSize,
          overflow: 'linebreak'
        },

      })

      doc.save('somename.pdf');

    }
  })
)

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. generate js file from the .ttf font file(use font converter online)
2. create **font.ts** file in your service folder
3. export const fontString : string ="AAEAAA"; <-- paste all string from generated file here

   ```
     import {fontString} from "./font";
     doc.addFileToVFS("AdriaSlabW00Medium.ttf", fontString);
     doc.addFont("AdriaSlabW00Medium.ttf", "Adria Slab W00 Medium", "normal");
     doc.setFont('Adria Slab W00 Medium', 'normal');
   ```